# Neo4j: How can I write this query better?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new in Neo4j. I tried to do this query:

> "Mati Gol would like to watch a new movie.  therefore would like to get the following list of movies: Write a query that returns all movies that were LIKED by any person who is a FRIEND of the person with the name Mati Gol or is a FRIEND of a FRIEND of Mati Gol, excluding all movies WATCHED by Mati Gol."

My query is:

```
MATCH (a:person {name:"Moti Gol"})-[:WATCHED]->(b)
WITH collect(b) AS Already_Watched
MATCH (a:person {name:"Moti Gol"})-[:FRIEND*1..2]->(b)-[:LIKED]->(c) 
WITH collect(c) AS Friend_Liked
(movie:Friend_Liked) WHERE NOT (movie.name) IN Already_Watched 
RETURN movie.name
```

Is this query OK? Can someone offer me better writing of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has some errors... Firstly, the first line has no MATCH statement. You are MATCHing `(a:person {name:"Moti Gol"})` two times and redeclaring the `a` variable.

A more simple and intuitive way to do the same query:

```
// get all the movies liked by friends or friends of friends of "Moti Gol"...
MATCH (a:person {name:"Moti Gol"})-[:FRIEND*1..2]->(b:person)-[:LIKED]->(c:movie)
// excluding all movies WATCHED by Mati Gol
WHERE NOT (a)-[:WATCHED]->(c)
// return the movies
RETURN c.name
```

Comment: yes, you right I forget the Match,
it was a typo when I write this query.
it's great and working! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which I think is what you were after from the start but didn't quite get right.

```
// find the person and the movies they have already watched
MATCH (a:Person {name:"Mati Gol"})-[:WATCHED]->(movie:Movie)
WITH a, collect(movie) as my_movie_list

// find the person's friends and the movies that they like
MATCH (a)-[:FRIEND*1..2]->(:Person)-[:LIKED]->(movie:Movie)
WITH a, my_movie_list, collect(DISTINCT movie) as friend_movie_list

// return the friend like movies that are not already watched
RETURN [m IN friend_movie_list WHERE NOT m in my_movie_list] as movies_to_watch
```

I think this solution gives you a little more cost certainty as it should only traverse the movie nodes once each. If there is a lot of duplication in movies LIKED by friends and friends of friends (which I expect is a reasonably likely scenario) then reducing the list of LIKED movies to the distinct list first and then filtering it against the movies watched afterwards could save on database comparisons.